# Destructuring key from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, destructuring

I'm new to javascript and I was wondering how I can destructure key from the nested object

```
const user = {
        'name': 'Alex',
        'address': '15th Park Avenue',
        'age': 43,
        skills: {
            "cs-s": ["scss", "tailwind"],
            "js": "react",
        },
    }

        ({ name: n, address: a } = user);

    console.log(`my name is ${n} my ${s} in ${c} is ${s} && ${t}`)
    //expected output is my name is Alex my skills in cs-s is scss and tailwind
```

I also try to do that but still give me the value and I want the key with full Destructuring  if it is possible

```
const member = {
        name: "Nour",
        skill: {
            "css": "scss",
            js: "React",
        },
    };
    let skillOne = Object.keys(user.skill)[0];
    console.log(skillOne);
    ({ name: n, skill: { [skillOne]: s } } = member);
    console.log(`${n} ${s}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you wanted (I think you need extra steps to get object keys), but here is a way:

```js
const user = {
    'name': 'Alex',
    'address': '15th Park Avenue',
    'age': 43,
    skills: {
        "cs-s": ["scss", "tailwind"],
        "js": "react",
    },
}

let { name, address, age, skills: { "cs-s": csSkills, "js": jsSkills } } = user;

//expected output is my name is Alex my skills in cs-s is scss and tailwind
console.log(`my name is ${name} my skills in cs-s is ${csSkills[0]} and ${csSkills[1]}`);
```

Although I think it's bad practice to destructure two layers of objects.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I was wondering how to get the "c-ss" and store it into a new variable like ${c}  you got me? ... is that even possible  here is another example if not 

const game = {
  title: "YS",
  developer: "Falcom",
  releases: {
    "Oath In Felghana": ["USA", "Japan"],
    "Ark Of Napishtim": {
      US: "20 USD",
      JAP: "10 USD",
    },
    Origin: "30 USD",
  },
};

console.log(`My Best Release Is ${o} It Released in ${u} & ${j}`);
// My Best Release Is Oath In Felghana It Released in USA & Japan

Comment: Yes you can, by using `Object.keys()`. Object destructuring is when you know the keys and want to know the values. Try it: `console.log(Object.keys(user.skills));`

Comment: I know it and try to do something like this but  was thinking there might be a way with Destructuring